# Do dice finish resolving before yielding Tokyo?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

When does yielding occur in relation to dice resolution? Simultaneously? After all dice have resolved? After attack dice are resolved?

For example (A for attack die, H for heart):

```
Alice is outside Tokyo, Bob is inside. It is now Alice's turn.
Alice rolls: 3, 3, 3, A, A, H
? Handle VP and hearts?
Alice attacks Bob
Bob chooses to yield
```

Now consider the possibility Alice has a single shrink ray token, so she only rolls 5 dice:

```
Alice is outside Tokyo, Bob is inside. It is now Alice's turn.
Alice rolls: 3, 3, 3, A, H
? Handle VP and hearts?
Alice attacks Bob
Bob chooses to yield
```

She must choose if the heart is applied to heal for one, or if it will remove the shrink ray token. In this case, order of resolution for the attack/yield and heart matters (more/less information for Alice & Bob, inability to heal in Tokyo). Is there an order to the dice resolution (eg hearts then attacks), or is the yield not declared until after all dice have resolved?

Comment: @ikegami So does is the decision to yield made after the dice resolve? I'm wondering due to the effect of hearts with shrink ray - the added information of what they use the heart for could potentially influence whether someone yields, while the added information of whether they yield could determine what they use the heart for.

Comment: @ikegami Sorry, I'm thinking the other direction: if Alice has been hit by the effect of Shrink Ray (not shown in my example above), she would have to choose what her heart was used for (heal 1 or remove 1 shrink ray token). The timing of Bob's decision to yield (or not) could obviously influence (or be influenced by) her choice of what to do with the heart. So the question is where does the yield fall (ie attack resolution) in relation to the rest of the dice?

Comment: @ikegami I updated the question with the second example I was outlining.

Comment: @ikegami Hence my question. What you can do with the heart changes based on when the yield occurs, and whether the yield occurs at all can also change based on the information of what the heart is used for. I'm wondering if there's some official ruling on the timing here: if dice are resolved simultaneously, is the yield after that? If they are resolved in order, what is that order and where does the yield fit in?

Comment: you accepted an answer, but there appears to be a mismatch. Ikagami is answering an older version of your question perhaps, but no where does he answer if you must decide to use a [heart] for healing or removing a shrink token before/after the monster in Tokyo decides to yield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is my opinion that the dice indicate what happens to you at your current location. A heart dice would indicate that you healed, if your location permits it.

This is partially supported by the fact that one must take all damage rolled even if one cedes Tokyo. You should similarly be able to use all hearts even if you are forced to take Tokyo. There's absolutely no mention or implication of any other possibility.

Everyone I've played with has naturally come to the same understanding. You could view podcasts of people playing KoT, but I'm sure they've come to the same conclusion.

> She must choose if the heart is applied to heal for one, or if it will remove the shrink ray token. In this case, order of resolution for the attack/yield and heart matters

No, it doesn't. According to the [FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/743476/faq-in-english-answered-by-gabriel-iello-in-a-fren) on BoardGameGeek, removing a bad counter counts as healing and is thus equally forbidden in Tokyo, so the order does not affect the choice.

Answer (score 1):

Alice chooses in which order to resolve dice and how to use them (heart for heal of to remove shrink ray). Alice get the opportunity to finish resolving ALL dice before Bob can declare yielding.

Comment: It this is an official iello representative, you might want to click on the [tag:King-of-tokyo] tag. There are several other KoT questions without official answers, and at least one question with two official answers that contradict.